# Pagination using retrofit

Tags: android-studio, pagination

I have a list which is being populated using retrofit (repository method). Now I want to add pagination onto it. Any help

I have done on scroll part using NestedScrollview. Here is the code snippet - `
binding.nestedScrollview.setOnScrollChangeListener(new
NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(@NonNull NestedScrollView v, int 
           scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            
           if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - 
               v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                   pageNo += 1;
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pageNo, 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
                  getWishLists(String.valueOf(pageNo));
            }
        }
    });
```

`

Please let me know if this is the correct approach